# Join bounded data with unbounded data using CoGroupByKey

Tags: join, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm joining data from two data sources:

- one is bounded, using `beam.io.ReadFromText`. It is a json.gz file
- one is unbounded, using `beam.io.ReadFromPubSub` + a Window `beam.WindowInto(beam.window.Sessions(3600), trigger=beam.trigger.Repeatedly(beam.trigger.AfterCount(1)), accumulation_mode=beam.trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)`

From both sides, the data is preprocessed, joined, processed again, then written to `BigQuery` using `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery`.

My goal is to join the data sources on a common field with `CoGroupByKey`. Using samples from both data sources, the join works on the [Apache Beam playground](https://play.beam.apache.org/).
However, since I am using a `Window` for the unbounded data, I'm having trouble performing the join. There are no errors and all the data is returned, but no join is performed.
Based on my research, here are the potential configurations for a `CoGroupByKey` operation:

- bounded data + bounded data without any `Window`: `CoGroupByKey` works and the join is done when there is a match
- bounded data + unbounded data with `Session/FixedWindow`: `CoGroupByKey` returns all data but no join performed
- unbounded data + unbounded data with `Window`: does not apply to my case, so did not try.

Note that to perform the join, I avoid using Side Inputs since our compressed file is already 35MB. We have performance issues when injecting the bounded data inside a `ParDo` function.

I also tried to replace `CoGroupByKey` with a `Flatten` + `GroupByKey` operations. Same results.